# What is angular2 typescript and angular2 ecma script

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular2.
What is the difference between Angular2 with typescript and angular2 with ecmascript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ECMAScript is the standard.  JavaScript is the implementation.  When people say ECMAScript they often mean JavaScript... the JavaScript that browsers understand.

[Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) is a "typed superset of JavaScript that compiles/transpiles to  JavaScript."  Today, that means you'll compile/transpile your TypeScript code into ECMAScript 5/ES5, since most browsers [support that version](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5).  In the future, as browser support grows for ECMASCript 6/ES6/ES2015, you could compile your TypeScript into ES2015 instead of ES5.

TypeScript's primary purpose is not to add features to JavaScript – as is the purpose of ES2015 – but to make it easier and safer for developers to write and maintain large JavaScript applications.
The primary benefit of TypeScript shows up before your application runs – when you're writing or maintaining code.  Intellisense, code completion, the ability to use ES2015 features today, etc.

Angular 2 is written in TypeScript.  If you write Angular 2 applications, I strongly recommend that you use TypeScript.

Comment: Why are you strongly recommend to write angular 2 apps in TypeScript only.?

Comment: @BharathKumar, a few reasons: most SO questions and answers use TypeScript -- meaning that most developers are using it;  it is more succinct (writing Angular 2 apps in ES5 is rather verbose); you get to use [ES2015 features](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) now -- e.g., classes, arrow functions, ..., let, for of, template strings, promises; if you use types, your TypeScript-aware editor will catch a lot of bugs for you; it looks good on your resume.

Answer (score 0):

As said above Ecmascript is a standard, which is implemented by Javascript. Javascript in some browsers currently implements Ecmascript 2015 standards(also called ES6), others don't.

Typescript is a super set of Ecmascript 2015 as it includes new stuffs like decorators etc.

ES5 Javascript is the most widely available javascript version almost all browsers support

Since not all browsers currently support ES6/Typescript, you have to convert your ES6 javascript code into ES5 javascript code that every browser understands(this process is called [transpiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler))